# Python Multiple Classes Error in Calling specific class

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, python-import

I am a newbie, and picking up Python (3.4) and trying to work on classes.

I have created a module BootstrapYieldCurve, with two classes (BootstrapYieldCurve and ForwardRates) inside.

When I import the module, I can call and manipulate the BootstrapYieldCurve class, but I get an error from calling the ForwardRates class.

Would someone be able to advise if the code is wrong, or the way I call the class in Python Shell?

```
>>> from BootstrapYieldCurve import ForwardRates
>>> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#36>", line 1, in <module>
    from BootstrapYieldCurve import ForwardRates
ImportError: cannot import name 'ForwardRates'
```

### This is my module code structure

```
import math

class BootstrapYieldCurve():
    def __init__(self):
    def add_instrument(..........):
    ..........
class ForwardRates():
    def .........
```

Comment: Did you perchance already import from this module during the same session, before you wrote the `ForwardRates` class? Modules are cached, if you added new things, that `import` won't work unless you do: `from importlib import reload`, `import BootstrapYieldCurve`, `reload(BootstrapYieldCurve)`, then repeat your `from x import y` statement.

Comment: hi ShadowRange, yes I did. I restarted my Python shell, and renamed the python file and classes. So, it does seem to work now. many thanks

Answer (score 1):

You cannot import one class from another class like this :

```
from BootstrapYieldCurve import ForwardRates
```

because `ForwardRates` is not encapsulated inside `BootstrapYieldCurve` (Also, there is no such concept in Python). See [encapsulation](https://pythonspot.com/en/encapsulation/).

You can import `variables, functions, and classes` from a `module` (a python file that generally have variables, functions, and classes)

You can do something like :

```
from module_file import BootstrapYieldCurve
```

and

```
from module_file import ForwardRates
```

You can refer to this [basic tutorial on importing modules](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/A_Beginner%27s_Python_Tutorial/Importing_Modules).

Also, try not to name `module` and `class` with `same name` as that may create confusion. It is a not a good practice to do that as module names share the same namespace as everything else.

Comment: Thanks Satish, I've changed my filename to be YieldCurve.py where I specify the classes BootstrapYieldCurve and ForwardRates inside. Then, I am able to import the ForwardRates using ' >>> from YieldCurve import ForwardRates'